# Implementation of graph in Java from Database

Tags: java

What I have is 2 tables :

```
    Users (id, name, lastname) 
    Friends (id1, id2)
```

Given these 2 tables, I need to be able to find the distance between 2 users d(id1,id2)

I defined a User class, that holds each of the user attribute in the table.

I need to build a graph. My data structure for the graph is

```
     Map<User, Set<User>>
```

mapping a user to a set of his friends.
How am I building the graph ? I queried the db for the ids of all the users in the db. I got an

```
   int[] userids
```

Then for each int in this array:

(1) I build a User object, fetching in the db the attributes of that user

(2) I query the Friends table in the db to have the ids of the friends of that user :

```
    int [] friends
```

(3) for each int in this friends array, I build a User object fetching in the db the attributes of that user and add it to

```
    Set<User> friends = new Set<User>();
```

Question 1 : Any ideas how to do this better ? It takes forever, given that I have 500 users, and 20000 entries in the Friends table ...

The big problem here is that when 2 users are the "same" in the database, they are referenced in differents objects in my graph !!

Which is messing up my distance algorithm. I start with a User u, get his Friends {f1,f2} , and when I wanna get the friends of friends using graph.get(f1) and graph.get(f2) I get null (for the reason stated in my problems, ie 1 db user in many different User objects)

I need to find a way to build my graph such that 1 given user say (1, John, Doe) is referenced in one and only User object in the heap ...

Question 2 : How ??

Thank you so much

[Help with Java Graph Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329427/help-with-java-graph-implementation)

Comment: How about storing all the userids in a set? that'll take care of the duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading one user at a time is going to be slow, that's lots of round-trips to the database.  It will be especially slow if there is no index on the `Friends` table.

You are better off just grabbing all the data from the database and building the graph in Java yourself.

```
select UserId, ... from Users;
```

as you are doing now, to build a `User` for each user.  You'll want to create a `Map` from `userId` to `User` for use in step 2 (so you don't get multiple `User` objects for the same `userId`).

```
select id1, id2 from Friends;
```

Then look up the two ids in the `Map` above, then add each `User` to the other `User`'s outbound edge set.

Comment: OK then my graph would become Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> (ids and ids of friends) and a Map<Integer, User> (id to user object) ?

Comment: The former could be `Map<User,Set<User>>` as well.  As a third option, I generally like to store the friend edges in `User` itself, i.e. `User` has an instance variable `Set<User>` which contains the friends of that user.  Personal preference, though, you could do it either way.

Comment: I have been working on this more, and what I have is the following : Map<Integer, User> : lookup table by id

Map<Integer, Set<Node>>, which maps a user_id to the nodes of his friends, and a  which is a look-up table. I